# HTTP SSL pipelining in Python

Tags: python, http

I’m working on a Python app that needs to send hundreds of HTTP requests in a short period of time to a web service that is SSL-only. Is there any support for [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) in Python?

Comment: Have you already tried sending these requests concurrently and found it's too slow? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010299/95735) is the list of questions regarding concurrent http requests in Python.

Comment: `requests` looks promising, I’ll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using Python's [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) module. As documented in [issue 13](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/issues/13), it's as simple as:

```
s = requests.session()
rs = [grequests.get(url, session=s) for url in urls]
grequests.map(rs)
```

Comment: Does this actually do HTTP pipelining as originally requested?  Or just separate async requests, each of which incurrs lots of connection latency, setup and overhead?

Comment: @nealmcb Things may have changed in the year since I poked at this, but I believe that while requests didn’t do real pipelining in the sense of sending a ton of requests all at once on one HTTP connection, it did reuse HTTP connections, and it was really really fast so that parsing and persisting the responses became the bottleneck.

Comment: Ahh - I was thinking of keep-alive, which is typically on by default.  Given requests.session(), this does seem on the right track, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes, though it's good you found a satisfactory solution to your own original problem, this doesn't really do much for those of us who are actually looking for real HTTP pipelining.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do actual pipelining, [this site](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576673-python-http-pipelining/) has a function that will do it for you. Tested with Wireshark, it allows sending requests without waiting for a response over a single connection.