# multiprocessing.dummy in Python is not utilising 100% cpu

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am doing a machine learning project in Python, so I have to do parallel predict function, which I'm using in my program.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def multi_predict(X, predict, *args, **kwargs):
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(predict, X)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results
```

The problem is that all my CPUs loaded only on 20-40% (in sum it's 100%). I use multiprocessing.dummy because I have some problems with multiprocessing module in pickling function.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

When you use [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy), you're using threads, not processes:

> `multiprocessing.dummy` replicates the API of `multiprocessing` but is no
>   more than a wrapper around the `threading` module.

That means you're restricted by the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), and only one thread can actually execute CPU-bound operations at a time. That's going to keep you from fully utilizing your CPUs. If you want get full parallelism across all available cores, you're going to need to address the pickling issue you're hitting with `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Note that `multiprocessing.dummy` might still be useful if the work you need to parallelize is IO bound, or utilizes a C-extension that releases the GIL. For pure Python code, however, you'll need `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Or use a non-GIL-based Python implementation like Jython or IronPython… or import the GIL-less STM version of PyPy from 2015. :)

Comment: [Python threads are real OS threads: they can run in parallel (if there are multiple CPU cores). Only pure Python code is limited by GIL. C extensions such as `lxml`, `regex`, `numpy` can and do release GIL and therefore several threads can and do run in parallel.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234301/synchronise-muti-threads-in-python#comment41151656_26234761)

Comment: @endolith: who knows. There could be numerous reasons. There is not enough information in the question. Note: at the time of my comment, the answer didn't even mention that GIL can be released. It is wrong to assume that *all* performance problems are due to GIL in a Python program with multiple threads.