# Simple multithread for loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, iteration

I searched everywhere and I don't find any simple example of iterating a loop with multithreading.

For example, how can I multithread this loop?

```
for item in range(0, 1000):
    print(item)
```

Is there any way to cut it in like 4 threads, so each thread has 250 iterations?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Easiest way is with [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) (which uses threads instead of processes) and a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp 

def do_print(s):
    print s

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=mp.Pool(4)
    p.map(do_print,range(0,10)) # range(0,1000) if you want to replicate your example
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Maybe you want to try real multiprocessing, too if you want to better utilize multiple CPUs but there are several caveats and [guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) to follow then.

Possibly other methods of `Pool` would better suit your needs - depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! What if I need to pass other arguments to the `do_print` function?

Comment: that depends - with multiprocessing.dummy there should be no problems but if you want to make sure you should put the args in the iterable - eg with [zip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) or [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: For some reason, this code creates about 60 (!) threads to iterate over `range(0, 1000)` for me (Python 3.5)...

Comment: @janbrohl: To avoid unnecessary temporaries, you'd want to use the Py3's `zip` (on Py2, [replace bad `zip` with good `zip` using `from future_builtins import zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip)) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions), so the arguments are produced lazily (as needed) instead of eagerly (delaying dispatch of first call and wasting memory).

Comment: @ForceBru: If you used `multiprocessing.dummy`, that should be impossible; the `Pool` constructor given is only using four worker threads.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, it should be impossible, but occurs when I use `imap` or `imap_unordered` instead of `map`. The first spawns around 10 threads (already quite odd), and the second one about 60 of them.

Comment: @ForceBru what's the actual code you are using so we could replicate what you see?

Comment: @miraculixx, the code in this answer, but with `map` replaced with `imap` or `imap_unordered` and `range(0, 1000)`.

Comment: @ForceBru how did you check the number of threads being created?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu, probably using [`threading.active_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.active_count).

Comment: Can you please answer answer on this link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724573/using-parallel-method-instead-of-sequential-loop]

Comment: very cool trick and very easy to set since is the same as multithread or multicore =)

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to do the splitting manually:

```
import threading

def ThFun(start, stop):
    for item in range(start, stop):
        print item

for n in range(0, 1000, 100):
    stop = n + 100 if n + 100 <= 1000 else 1000
    threading.Thread(target = ThFun, args = (n, stop)).start()
```

This code uses *multithreading*, which means that everything will be run within a single Python process (i.e. only one Python interpreter will be launched).

*Multiprocessing*, discussed in the other answer, means *running some code in several Python interpreters* (in several *processes*, not *threads*). This may make use of all the CPU cores available, so this is useful when you're focusing on the speed of your code (*print a ton of numbers until the terminal hates you!*), not simply on parallel processing. <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. `multiprocessing.dummy` turns out to be [a wrapper around the `threading` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432411/multiprocessing-dummy-in-python). `multiprocessing` and `multiprocessing.dummy` have the same interface, but the first module does parallel processing using *processes*, while the latter - using *threads*.</sup>

Comment: multiprocessing.dummy actually uses threads - edited my answer to make that more clear

Comment: `multiprocessing.dummy` is indeed a wrapper around the `threading` module, but `multiprocessing` itself works exactly as described in the crossed-out part of the answer. Which one is chosen depends on what behavior one wants, the code is the very same (that's a good thing).

Comment: @miraculixx, this is why I decided not to remove the now crossed-out part completely: `multiprocessing` and `multiprocessing.dummy` have similar interfaces, but the choice of a module affects the behavior (threads vs processes).

Comment: @ForceBru I see, the problem is that it now looks as though what you wrote is incorrect, which it isn't, possibly confusing someone looking for multiprocessing ... `multiprocessing` and `multiprocessing.dummy` have the _exact same_ interface, that's the whole point.

Comment: @miraculixx: Not exactly, but close enough, and they try to keep them consistent. `multiprocessing.dummy` accidentally omitted the `cpu_count` function for example.

Comment: can you please answer on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724573/using-parallel-method-instead-of-sequential-loop  ?

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3.2, the [`concurrent.futures` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) provides primitives to [concurrently `map` a function across iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map). Since `map` and `for` are closely related, this allows to easily convert a `for` loop into a multi-threaded/multi-processed loop:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(print, range(0, 1000))
```