# Parallelise / Threading a big for loop | Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a working `Jupyter Notebook` that models fake data in the form of a `dictionary`. Using `Faker` library and other basic `Python`.

Reading other posts, `parallelism` seems to be used on methods. However, I want to apply this technique on the big `for loop`; as I have many more *"key-value lists"* applied in the process.

Note: I've appended comments of `list slicing` included in the process, in case that's needed.

Is it possible to run multiple iterations of a `for loop` at once? (or as many as possible)

```
from faker import Faker
faker = Faker()
Faker.seed(1)

import pandas as pd

import random
random.seed(1)

# Key Value lists
biographic_keys = [['Name', 'faker.unique.name()'], ['Aliases', 'faker.unique.user_name()'], ['Date of birth', 'faker.unique.date_of_birth().isoformat()'], ['Phone numbers', 'faker.unique.phone_number()'], ['Addresses', 'faker.unique.address()'], ['Nationality', 'faker.unique.country()'], ['Social Security Number', 'faker.unique.ssn()'], ['Alien File Number', 'random.randrange(1000000, 999999999, random.randint(7, 9))']]
biometric_keys = [['Height', "'{}ft {}inch'.format(random.randint(4, 7), random.randint(0, 11)) if random.randint(0, 1) == 1 else '{}cm'.format(random.randint(100, 200))"], ['Weight', "'{}kg'.format(random.randint(60, 130)) if random.randint(0, 1) == 1 else '{}st {}lb'.format(random.randint(7, 50), random.randint(0, 13))"], ['Eye color', "random.choice(['Amber', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Gray', 'Green', 'Hazel'])"], ['Hair color', "random.choice(['Brown', 'Blond', 'Black', 'Auburn', 'Red', 'Gray', 'White', 'Bald'])"]]

entries = 4
alien_key_val = []
alien_key_val.append(["Biographic data", biographic_keys])
alien_key_val.append(["Biometric data", biometric_keys])

#print(alien_key_val[0]) # name, subset
#print(alien_key_val[0][0]) # name
#print(alien_key_val[0][1]) # subset
#print(alien_key_val[0][1][0][0]) # key
#print(alien_key_val[0][1][0][1]) # invoke val

# Programmatic key-values
alien_dict = {}

for entry in range(1, entries+1):
    entry_dict = {}
    for i, subset in enumerate(alien_key_val):
        subset_dict = {}
        subset_name = alien_key_val[i][0]
        for data in subset[1]:
            key, invoc = data[0], data[1]
            #if ('faker.unique.' in invoc) or ('random.' in invoc) or ('tf.' in invoc) or ("''.join" in invoc) or ("'{}" in invoc): val = eval(invoc)
            if invoc[-1] != ':': val = eval(invoc)
            else: val = ""
            if 'Identification numbers' in key: val = {i[0]: i[1] for i in val}
            subset_dict.update({key: val})
        entry_dict.update({subset_name: subset_dict})
    alien_dict.update({'id_' + str(entry): entry_dict})

print("\nALIEN_DICT:\n", alien_dict)
```

```
>>> ALIEN_DICT:
 {'id_1': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Ryan Gallagher', 'Aliases': 'david77', 'Date of birth': '1994-03-12', 'Phone numbers': '(317)066-9074x3915', 'Addresses': '806 Tanya Stream\nNew Jeffreymouth, OH 31051', 'Nationality': 'Guatemala', 'Social Security Number': '237-87-3585', 'Alien File Number': 119580763}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '4ft 7inch', 'Weight': '120kg', 'Eye color': 'Hazel', 'Hair color': 'White'}}, 'id_2': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Tiffany House', 'Aliases': 'jmonroe', 'Date of birth': '1992-12-05', 'Phone numbers': '241-586-8344', 'Addresses': '690 Sanchez Union Suite 625\nChristopherhaven, WI 21957', 'Nationality': 'Maldives', 'Social Security Number': '861-51-6071', 'Alien File Number': 177366680}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '4ft 6inch', 'Weight': '60kg', 'Eye color': 'Hazel', 'Hair color': 'Bald'}}, 'id_3': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Allen Williams DDS', 'Aliases': 'kholland', 'Date of birth': '1973-11-13', 'Phone numbers': '038.836.8595', 'Addresses': '890 Bowers View Apt. 883\nHerringfort, MN 75211', 'Nationality': 'Mexico', 'Social Security Number': '205-65-6774', 'Alien File Number': 775747704}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '175cm', 'Weight': '27st 0lb', 'Eye color': 'Amber', 'Hair color': 'Brown'}}, 'id_4': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Mr. Gregory Ryan', 'Aliases': 'stephen03', 'Date of birth': '1991-12-27', 'Phone numbers': '(892)184-0110', 'Addresses': '41925 Jones Estate Suite 824\nShawnmouth, NJ 15468', 'Nationality': 'Anguilla', 'Social Security Number': '320-50-5626', 'Alien File Number': 655004368}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '148cm', 'Weight': '34st 11lb', 'Eye color': 'Amber', 'Hair color': 'Auburn'}}}
```

---

**Solution** appended below. Please add a solution if you believe yours is a better alternative. I'd love to learn other approaches for the future.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access every element in the loop simultaneously?
How about multi threading ?

Comment: I *think* I do :). Interesting ok, how might I do that? The end goal is to have the process run much faster with maintained stability.

Comment: I think you can loop to create thread first. Then, all thread will start running and no longer looping. but I am not sure will it become faster.

Comment: I have appended a solution below, based on your suggestion. However, how do I add them all together, in order of `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [Simple multithread for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856172/simple-multithread-for-loop-in-python)
 top solution.

Using `multiprocessing.dummy as mp` and converting my `for loop` grand procedure into a `function`.

All *"entry"* dictionaries are collected into `list` `dicts` and are added to `dictionary` `big_boi_dict` as originally intended.

```
...

def alien_dict_func(entry):
    # Programmatic key-values
    alien_dict = {}

    entry_dict = {}
    for i, subset in enumerate(alien_key_val):
        subset_dict = {}
        subset_name = alien_key_val[i][0]
        for data in subset[1]:
            key, invoc = data[0], data[1]
            #if ('faker.unique.' in invoc) or ('random.' in invoc) or ('tf.' in invoc) or ("''.join" in invoc) or ("'{}" in invoc): val = eval(invoc)
            if invoc[-1] != ':': val = eval(invoc)
            else: val = ""
            if 'Identification numbers' in key: val = {i[0]: i[1] for i in val}
            subset_dict.update({key: val})
        entry_dict.update({subset_name: subset_dict})
    alien_dict.update({'id_' + str(entry): entry_dict})

    #print("\nALIEN_DICT:\n", alien_dict)
    return alien_dict


import multiprocessing.dummy as mp 

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=mp.Pool(4)
    dicts = p.map(alien_dict_func, range(1, entries+1)) # range(0,1000) if you want to replicate your example
    #print("DICTS: ", dicts)
    big_boi_dict = {}
    for d in dicts: big_boi_dict.update(d)
    print("big_boi_dict: ", big_boi_dict)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

```
>>> big_boi_dict:  {'id_1': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Jacob Gaines', 'Aliases': 'laurenswanson', 'Date of birth': '2016-04-20', 'Phone numbers': '630-868-7169x899', 'Addresses': '0340 Lydia Passage Suite 898\nAliciaside, NC 54017', 'Nationality': 'Netherlands Antilles', 'Social Security Number': '646-75-5043', 'Alien File Number': 216185864}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '4ft 3inch', 'Weight': '84kg', 'Eye color': 'Gray', 'Hair color': 'Blond'}}, 'id_2': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Carlos Wallace', 'Aliases': 'andreabray', 'Date of birth': '1927-09-11', 'Phone numbers': '069-056-6401x106', 'Addresses': '7567 Timothy Drive Suite 202\nMichealberg, WY 38137', 'Nationality': 'Zambia', 'Social Security Number': '423-34-8418', 'Alien File Number': 472177351}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '7ft 0inch', 'Weight': '111kg', 'Eye color': 'Amber', 'Hair color': 'Brown'}}, 'id_3': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Jason Hill', 'Aliases': 'kimberly73', 'Date of birth': '2002-11-20', 'Phone numbers': '661.123.2301x4271', 'Addresses': '16908 Amanda Key\nLake Taraville, OH 89507', 'Nationality': 'Italy', 'Social Security Number': '855-86-1944', 'Alien File Number': 20427192}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '125cm', 'Weight': '77kg', 'Eye color': 'Brown', 'Hair color': 'White'}}, 'id_4': {'Biographic data': {'Name': 'Melinda White PhD', 'Aliases': 'hartmanerica', 'Date of birth': '1917-05-19', 'Phone numbers': '(174)876-1971x2693', 'Addresses': '8478 Kristina Road Suite 710\nSaraview, ND 82480', 'Nationality': 'French Southern Territories', 'Social Security Number': '779-13-3745', 'Alien File Number': 501832948}, 'Biometric data': {'Height': '148cm', 'Weight': '128kg', 'Eye color': 'Gray', 'Hair color': 'Auburn'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question of accessing every element in the loop simultaneously. I tried something like that

```
import time
import threading


class handle_data(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):   # handle_data
      print ("Starting " + self.name)
      print(self.name, 5, self.counter)
      print("Exiting " + self.name)


    def stop(self):
        self.running = False    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for data in range(10):
        handle_data(data,"Thread-"+str(data),data).start()
```

Comment: I will try this now

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420  I just edit the code and delete one of the for loop