# Using parallel method instead of sequential loop

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

I have code where already loop is used and I want to replace loop with multithreading, but not able to understand how to do. below is code.

```
def run_test_function(arg1,arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
   try:
      #loop1
      for x in arg1:
         #loop2
         for y in arg2:
            #loop3
            for z in range(len(arg3)):
               #statements
            #statements
         #statements
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
def main(argv):
   arg1 = value1
   arg2 = value2
   arg3 = value3
   arg4 = value4
   run_test_function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

I want every iteration of loop1 should behave as a thread, so that I can replace loop with multithreading. Appreciation and thanks in advance for help. :)

Comment: This entirely depends on what the `statements` are

Comment: statements are like few kubectl commands and processing their output and validating the output. Lets say statements are like printing x n y of two loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print `x` and `y` in parallel (as you said in the comment):

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool


def run_test_function(arg1, arg2):
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.starmap(print, product(arg1, arg2), 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test_function([1,2,3,4,5], "abc")
```

- [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) imitates nested loops
- [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) provides parallelism

  - [`Pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) executes functions using the `Pool`

---

Output:

```
~/test $ python so.py
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
3 a
3 b
3 c
4 a
4 b
4 c
5 a
5 b
5 c
6 a
6 b
6 c
7 a
7 b
7 c
```

Comment: I apologize but not able to understand how to implement it for my code. I have edited my question, can you please look into it and see what is actually happening with my code.

Comment: If `arg3` and `arg4` are constants, you can pass a lambda function: `pool.map(lambda x, y: processing_function(x, y, arg3, arg4), product(arg1, arg2))`

Comment: what is the functionality of product and Pool(4) and according to you I need to place the statements in different function and have to call that function in run_test_function?

Comment: "what is the functionality of `product` and `Pool(4)`" - you can find links to the documentation are right after the code in the answer. "I need to place the statements in different function and have to call that function in run_test_function?" - yes

Comment: thank you, you cleared a lot, one more question, what if there is one more nested loop as loop3 and loop3 is like for x in range(len(arg3)) ? I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Simply put the `range(len(arg3))` into `product`: `product(arg1, arg2, range(len(arg3)))`. `product` is specifically designed to let you replace `N` nested loops like `for a in A: for b in B: for c in C: ...` with a call to `product` with `N` arguments, like `for a, b, c, d, e in product(A, B, C, D, E): ...`

Comment: thank you, but I think product won't help me, bcoz I just want loop1's each iteration should behave as single thread. Can you please look into the question's edited part? I apologize for asking many questions, but I think I am progressing on my problem and getting clarified after every step I edit.

Comment: Using the same lambda function trick and assuming that all `arg`s except maybe `arg1` are constants: `pool.map(lambda x: processing_function(x, arg2, arg3, arg4), arg1)`, where `processing_function` loops over `arg2, arg3, arg4` sequentially

Comment: thank you, Can you convert the same code in python 2.7

Comment: @AdeepMalmotra, ~~there are tools that can do this automatically~~ Oops, these tools convert Python 2.7 to Python 3, though. Anyway, this is a different question now

Comment: I have raised new question, can you please reply on the this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814939/converting-multiprocessing-python-3-code-to-python-2