# Python multiprocessing pool is slower than sequential

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have used multiprocessing Pool to get some performance benefit over my sequential approach. However result is just opposite and Pool takes more time than sequential:

```html
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list = []

    # parallel processing function
    def foo_pool(self, data):
        for d in data:
            d[0] = d[0] * 10
        return data

    # sequential function
    def foo_seq(self, data):
        data[0] = data[0] * 10
        return  data

    def log_result(self, result):
        # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
        self.result_list.extend([result])

    def apply_async_with_callback(self):
        pool = mp.Pool(8)

        # Data Creation
        lst = []
        for i in range(100000):
            lst.append([i, i + 1, i + 2])

        print('length of data ', len(lst))

        dtStart = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('start time:', str(datetime.datetime.now()))

        # Multiprocessing takes 2 secs
        for data in self.chunks(lst, 1000):
            pool.apply_async(self.foo_pool, args=(data,),
                             callback=self.log_result)

        # Sequential. It is 10x faster than pool
        # for d in lst:
        #     self.result_list.extend([self.foo_seq(d)])


        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print('output data length:', len(self.result_list))

        dtEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('end time:', str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print('Time taken:', str(dtEnd - dtStart))

    # Divide big data into chunks
    def chunks(self, data, n):
        for i in range(0, len(data), n):
            res = data[i:i + n]
            yield res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.apply_async_with_callback()
```

In above python code, in apply_async_with_callback(). If you un-comment the sequential code and run, result would get 10 times faster then multiprocessing Pool code.

Can someone help me understand, what is the wrong thing i am doing?

**Edit:**
After applying the code provided in [Why is multiprocessed code in given code taking more time than usual sequential execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291628/why-is-multiprocessed-code-in-given-code-taking-more-time-than-usual-sequential)

sequential is now only 2 times faster than parallel processing code. Updated code below:

```html
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list = []

    # parallel processing function
    def foo_pool(self, data):
        for d in data:
            d[0] = d[0] * float(10) + 10 * (float(d[0]) / 100)
        return data

    def log_result(self, result):
        # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
        self.result_list.extend([result])

    def flatten(self, ll):
        lst = []
        for l in ll:
            lst.extend(l)
        return lst

    def square(self, x):
        return x * x

    def squareChunk(self, chunk):
        return self.foo_pool(chunk) #[self.foo_pool(x) for x in chunk]

    def apply_async_with_callback(self):

        # Data Creation
        lst = []
        for i in range(1000000):
            lst.append([i, i + 1, i + 2])

        print('length of data ', len(lst))

        chunked = self.chunks(lst, 10000)  # split original list in decent sized chunks
        pool = mp.Pool(2)
        dtStart = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('start time:', str(datetime.datetime.now()))

        results = self.flatten(pool.map(self.squareChunk, chunked))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print('output data length:', len(results))

        dtEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('end time:', str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print('multi proc Time taken:', str(dtEnd - dtStart))


    def chunks(self, l, n):
        n = max(1, n)
        return (l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.apply_async_with_callback()
```

I can see the difference of using **Pool.map** instead of **Pool.apply_async**. Code is faster now. Earlier it was 10 times slower than sequential, now it is 2 times slower. But... slower....

This is how multiprocessing behaves? Then what is the point of using multiprocessing? Or am i still doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is multiprocessed code in given code taking more time than usual sequential execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291628/why-is-multiprocessed-code-in-given-code-taking-more-time-than-usual-sequential)

Comment: @e4c5 thanks for the link. performance has improved. However still slower that sequential.

Comment: but the whole point is that if the task is not trivial muti processing will always be slower because of the overheads. It's only faster if you have at least two long running tasks and at least two CPU cores available