# How do I parallelize a function with one argument in Python?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a list and returns the list of lists of `ngrams` (here n = 2). How can I parallelize  this function so that running time can be reduced?

I'm trying this, but it's not working. The `data_list` is a list of strings.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from collections import OrderedDict

grams_list = []
data_list = ["Hello, I am learning Python",
             "Python is a very Powerful language",
             "And Learning python is easy" ]




def ngrams(input, n):
    input = input.split(' ')
    output = []    
    for i in range(len(input) - n + 1):
        output.append(input[i:i + n])
    return output

def generating_grams_list(data_list):
    for j in range(0, len(data_list)):
        grams = [' '.join(x) for x in ngrams(data_list[j], 2)]  # Creating ngrams
        grams_list.append(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(grams)))  # removing duplicates
        # print "Creating ngrams list for each data string ", j
    return grams_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(generating_grams_list, data_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for result in results:
        print("result", result)
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Is there an error? Are the results not as expected? Using the `dummy` module you won't get any parallelization. Concurrency is not the same as parallelism

Comment: @karlson Result is not as expected

Comment: Why not extend your question with what the result is, and what you would have expected?

Comment: Why are you using `multiprocessing.dummy`? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432411/multiprocessing-dummy-in-python-is-not-utilising-100-cpu)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with the `multiprocessing.dummy` module you won't reduce the duration of your program as it distributes work across threads, not processes. That means that the computation will still run on only one processor. For the difference between concurrency and parallelism see for instance [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference)

To get real parallelization you need to spread the work across mutiple processes, e.g. using a [process pool](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) instead.

To address your actual problem (if I'm guessing right, since you didn't exactly say what your problem is):

You probably want `data_list` to be a list of lists of strings instead of a list of strings. With the code as it stands (ie. if `data_list` and `grams_list` were actually defined) you'd be sending a single string to each invocation of `generating_grams_list`, which is most likely not what you want as the for loop wouldn't make any sense (you'd be looping over characters).

As a side note: The pattern `for j in range(len(x)): func(x[j])` can better be written as `for j, item in enumerate(x): func(item)`.