# Fast, multiple regular expression string match with python

Tags: python, regex, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to match many string regexes into one long string and counting delimiters on every match. Using `multiprocessing` to concurrently search many regex at once:

```
with open('many_regex', 'r') as f:
    sch = f.readlines()

with open('big_string', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

import re
def search_sch(sch,text = text):
    delim_index = []
    last_found = 0
    for match in re.finditer(sch, text):
        count_delims = len(re.findall('##', text[last_found:match.start()]))
        if delim_index:
            count_delims += delim_index[-1]
        delim_index.append(count_delims)
        last_found = match.end()
    return delim_index

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

with Pool(8) as threadpool:
    matches = threadpool.map(search_sch, sch[:100])
```

The `threadpool.map` takes about 25s to execute, and only a single CPU core being utilised. Any idea why more cores are not being used? Also, any python library to do this fast?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432411/multiprocessing-dummy-in-python-is-not-utilising-100-cpu/26432431

Comment: This document suggests that threadpool is only useful for IO bound operations, since the GIL prevents two threads actually processing simultaneously: http://lucasb.eyer.be/snips/python-thread-pool.html . Perhaps there is a way to restructure with multiprocess pools?

Comment: What's the structure of `sch`? Is it just a single long regex with alternations of static strings like `alice|bob|charlie|...` or something more-complex? In the more-complex case, could that involve backtracking?

Comment: `sch` is a complex regex and matching them would probably involve backtracking, but I am treating each regex independently, so I fail to get why is it relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Pool` class from `multiprocessing.dummy` uses threading instead of multiprocessing. This means that the global interpreter lock is an issue. You want to use actual multiprocessing; for that, replace

`from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool`

for

`from multiprocessing import Pool`

Comment: Now it keeps running for >10min on Windows 7, python 3 (anaconda 4.4), have to force stop.

Comment: Running it from ipython console was the issue. From command prompt, works fine.