# Multiprocessing.dummy.Pool has only one worker running

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have created a class in which I store several large dictionaries and a method that takes as input a file and process it using the informations contained in the dictionaries.

Now, the total amount of files that I have to process is around 18000 so I opted to use a `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` in this way:

```py
with dummy.Pool(processes=50) as pool:
    failed = [x for x in pool.imap(export.get_uniref_uniprotkb_from_panproteome, species, chunksize=300)]
```

What I noticed in `htop` is that the main process spawns correctly 50 threads but only one is in running state even I change the chunksize.

Comment: You have to close the pool and then join as well. pool.close(), pool.join().

Comment: Python threads generally don't run concurrently because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Because of that, they're of little help in speeding up compute-bound processing. Using "real" multiprocessing might offer some improvement, depending on exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiprocessing.dummy in Python is not utilising 100% cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432411/multiprocessing-dummy-in-python-is-not-utilising-100-cpu)

Comment: @LavanyaPant I'm usintg the `with` statement

Comment: @Francesco  You may not require close but pool.join is require.