# Multithreading using way too much CPU

Tags: python, multithreading

I am doing:

```
pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(1)
```

and task manager says Python is using >30% CPU. I have an i5 9600K - has 6 cores. I am running the script from cmd if that means anything. If I use 8 threads, Python uses nearly 100% of the CPU. Is this expected?

Comment: (I generally don't do python, but this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432411/multiprocessing-dummy-in-python-is-not-utilising-100-cpu)

Comment: Take task manager's measurements with a pinch of salt - [even Microsoft themselves say so](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/873289/task-manager-may-not-calculate-cpu-usage-correctly-on-windows-2000-win).

Comment: The thing is, I notice considerably slower performance even when opening file explorer etc. so it must've been consuming a lot of CPU.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing multiprocessing, not multithreading, in which case your title and tags aren't quite correct.

Comment: In my understanding, `multiprocessing.dummy` uses threads as opposed to processes.