# Using multiprocessing in python to return values

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

**Background**

I have some code that looks like this right now.

```
failed_player_ids: Set[str] = set()
for player_id in player_ids:
    success = player_api.send_results(
        player_id, user=user, send_health_results=True
    )
    if not success:
        failed_player_ids.add(player_id)
```

This code works well but the problem is this is taking 5 seconds per call. There is a rate limit of 2000 calls per minute so i am way under the max capacity. I want to parallelize this to speed things up. This is my first time using `multiprocessing` library in python and hence I am a little confused as to how i should proceed. I can describe what i want to do in words.

In my current code i am loop through list of `player_id` and if api response is success I do nothing and if it failed i make note of that player id.

I am not sure how to implement paralleled version of this code. I have some idea but i am a little confused.

This is what i though of so far

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


    
    num_processors_to_use = 5 # This is a number can be increased to get more speed
    
    def send_player_result(player_id_list: List[str]) -> Optional[str]:
        for player_id in player_id_list:
            success = player_api.send_results(player_id, user=user, send_health_results=True)
            if not success:
                return player_id
    # Caller
    with Pool(processes=num_processors_to_use) as pool:
            responses = pool.map(
                func=send_player_result,
                iterable=player_id_list,
            )
            failed_player_ids = Set(responses)
```

Any comments and suggestions would help.

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/3216427

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3033952/3216427

Comment: @joanis Thank you the first post is a great find. I would also highly appreciate if it is not too difficult / time consuming for you if you could explain / correct my posted answer above with your comment. I feel it may help me understand better.

Comment: What does what you wrote actually do? Is it working yet or not?

Comment: PS: I've never done multiprocessor stuff in Python yet, I just recognized having reviewed questions about it recently. Hopefully someone else here will be able to comment on your code, if you indicate in what way it's not working yet.

Comment: PPS: I think you made a mistake in cutting and pasting the code, because you have two lines that start with `def send_player_result(` and I'm guessing the first one should not be there.

Comment: @joanis good catch i removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using function `map`, then each *item* of the *iterable* `player_id_list` will be passed as a separate task to function `send_player_result`. Consequently, this function should no longer be expecting to be passed a list of player ids, but rather a single player id. And, as you know by now, if your tasks are largely I/O bound, then multithreading is a better model. You can either:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
# or
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
```

You will probably want to greatly increase the number of threads (but not greater than the size of `player_id_list`):

```py
#from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from typing import Set

def send_player_result(player_id):
    success = player_api.send_results(player_id, user=user, send_health_results=True)
    return success

# Only required for Windows if you are doing multiprocessing:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    pool_size = 5 # This is a number can be increased to get more concurrency
    
    # Caller
    failed_player_ids: Set[str] = set()
    with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        results = pool.map(func=send_player_result, iterable=player_id_list)
        for idx, success in enumerate(results):
            if not success:
                # failed for argument player_id_list[idx]:
                failed_player_ids.add(player_id_list[idx])
```

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful explanation. I had a few follow up questions. What is the difference between `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` and doing `from multiprocessing import Pool`

Lastly if i decide to use multithreading then would i use the latter option you provided which is `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` ??

Comment: I found answer to my first question on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432411/multiprocessing-dummy-in-python-is-not-utilising-100-cpu#:~:text=threads%2C%20not%20processes%3A-,multiprocessing.,from%20fully%20utilizing%20your%20CPUs.)

Comment: Would i not be limited and not achieve any parallelsim by using .dummy?

Also my original solution where i loop through each player id and make the api call takes 5 seconds per call. Is it safe to assume that now i make 5 calls per 5 seconds so I am essentially making 60 calls per minute?

Comment: I wish i could upvote your answer as well, unfortunately my reputation is only 13 points so i am not able to do that.

Comment: `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` is equivalent to `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` and uses multithreading rather than multiprocessing (the underlying class will actually be `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` in the multithreading case and `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` in the multiprocessing case. If your tasks are mostly doing I/O (such as posting to a URL) your tasks are in a wait state most of the time and the known problem with multithreading, i.e. locking on the GIL is not much of a problem. Threads are much cheaper to create and easier to work with. (more)

Comment: If your worker function is CPU-intensive, then you want `from multiprocessing import Pool` or `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool` (you end up with the same result). I can't make any predictions on what your throughput will be. I don't even have any idea what your worker functions is doing or whether it is really I/O or CPU-intensive.